# Pass child element as props in React

Tags: reactjs, components, gatsby, react-props

I'm building simple site using Gatsby and styled-components. Here's my navigation component so far:

```
const Navigation = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <List>
      <NavItem><StyledLink to={'/converter/'}>Go to Converter</StyledLink></NavItem>
      <NavItem><StyledLink to={'/about/'}>Go to About</StyledLink></NavItem>
      <NavItem><StyledLink to={'/'}>Go to Main Page</StyledLink></NavItem>
    </List>
  </NavigationContainer>

)
```

I would like to use this component on every site but with different `<NavItem>` text and links. I don't have an idea how it could work with this component i.e. :

```
const About = () => (
  <>
    <Body>
      <Navigation />
    </Body>
  </>
)
```

So on different sites i want the `Navigation` component to have links to different pages and text in it. Is possible to achieve it using `props` ?

Comment: So do you mean to say that you want to conditionally render a different site / link based on which props are passed in?

Comment: Yes. Because on each site I want to have a slightly different navigation links set. For example on About page I don't want to have a link to About page etc.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of the problem you are trying to solve, you could always use a filter function to render routes based on which route the person is currently on:

```
const routes = [{
  to: '/converter/,
  message: 'Go to Converter',
},
{
  to: '/about/',
  message: 'Go to About',
},
{
  to: '/'
  message: 'Go to Main Page',
}];

const Navigation = (currentLocation) => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <List>
      {routes.filter(route => {
           if (route.to !== currentLocation) {
              return <NavItem><StyledLink to={route.to}>{route.message}</StyledLink></NavItem>
           }
        })
      }
    </List>
  </NavigationContainer>
)
```

In this case, you would need to determine the current location of where the user is on the site, and simply pass that property in to the navigation component.

Comment: Thank You. Looks that it should work. But I'm missing something. How can I define the `currentLocation` as props ? Say I have a ` <Navigation />` in About section, how to pass `currentLocation` here ?

Comment: That would all depend on how your app is structured, and what information you have available to you. 
If your About Component is a child of the Navigation Component, a feasible option would be to create a function in the parent component that would be invoked whenever a route was changed. That invocation would set the state in the state locally so that you could perform the filter without having to pass in a property. Another option would be to listen for a change in the location.pathname, but I wouldn't recommend adding listeners unnecessarily

Comment: The `About` page is a Gatsby page and the <`Navigation />` is nested inside it.
So it looks like: 
```const About = () => (
   <div>
      <Navigation />
   </div>
)
```